# Proving or Disproving Big-O Big-Θ help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm really new at this, so I would love some  help walking through these

Prove or disprove:

a) $f(n) = 2^{n+1} = O(2^n)$

b) $f(n) = 2^{n+1} = \theta(2^n)$

c) $f(n) = 2^{2n} = O(2^n)$

d) $f(n) = 2^{2n} = \theta(2^n)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Def**:
$$ f =\mathcal{\theta}(g): \exists N>0, C_1 > 0, C_2 > 0: \forall n \ge N, C_1 \cdot f(n) \le g(n) \le C_2 \cdot f(n)$$
$$ f =\mathcal{O}(g): \exists N>0, C > 0: \forall n \ge N, f(n) \le C \cdot g(n)$$
**Solution**:
$$a)~True.~f(n) = 2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^n \le 2\cdot g(n) = 2 \cdot 2^n$$
$$b)~True.~f(n) = 2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^n, g(n) \le f(n) \le 2\cdot g(n)$$
$$c)~False.~f(n) = 2^{2n} = 4^n.~If~4^n \le C\cdot 2^n \Rightarrow 2^n \le C \Rightarrow n \le \log{C}$$
$$d)~is~false, because~c)~is~false$$